# C# - Переливка данных из БД MS SQL в БД Oracle

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle

Есть таблица с одинаковыми именами и типами полей в БД MS SQL и Oracle (типы "одинаковы" насколько это возможно для разных СУБД). Как можно перелить данные с одной таблицы в другую, не перечисляя имена и типы полей явно? Иными словами, как динамически создавать команды INSERT с нужными именами, типами полей и данными?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Взять ORM, например [linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db), создать POCO-класс для таблицы, создать два подключения (к MS SQL и Oracle), прочитать данные из источника, залить данные в приемник, используя Bulk Copy. Например:

```
[Table(Name = "ProductsTemp")]
public class ProductTemp
{
  public int ProductID { get; set; }

  [Column(Name = "ProductName"), NotNull]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  // ... other columns ...
}

list = List<ProductTemp>

using (var db = new DbNorthwind())
{
  db.BulkCopy(list);
}
```

SQL-запрос для вставки создаст сама ORM. Перечислить колонки все же придется, но только при создании POCO-класса. Вручную запрашивать информацию о таблице, мапить типы данных между двумя СУБД - дело неблагодарное, лучше доверить его ORM.

Еще как вариант - использовать DataTable.

Примерные шаги:

- считать данные (например, с помощью OracleDataReader)
- сформировать DataTable
- залить данные через SqlBulkCopy

Пример можно посмотреть [здесь](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19090/Oracle-to-SQL-Server-VB-NET-Utility-application).
Предположительно, этот вариант будет медленнее, чем первый. Но не требует дополнительных библиотек, если данное обстоятельство является проблемой.

Comment: Вариант неплохой, спасибо. А можно сделать это без использования дополнительных библиотек?

Comment: @DarkGenius дополнил ответ.